# I want to create a class to create a file, and use main class to check if that file is created, but my code fail. (Java)

Tags: java, file

```
public class Fileverifynanoha 
{
    private File fileext;
    private Path filepath;
    public Fileverifynanoha()//this class wants to create a file, write something, and close it.
{
    filepath = Paths.get("./txttest.txt");
    Charset charset = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");
    String s = "Takamachi Nanoha. Shirasaki Tsugumi.!";
    try (BufferedWriter filewriter = Files.newBufferedWriter(filepath,charset))
    {
        filewriter.write(s,0,s.length()-1);   
    }
    catch(IOException e)
         {
            System.err.println(e);
         }

}//end of this class
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args)//the main method will check if this file contains(created), if so, return exist. if not, return doesnt exist.
{

    if (filetxt.exists()&&!filetxt.isDirectory())//object does not create any real thing, therefore nothing true will return.
    {
        System.out.println("File exist.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("File does not exist.");
    }
}
}
```

Here is the code. I want to use the class I create to create a file, write something. Then, I use main class to check if that file exist.

However, I don't know why, but the main class does not recognise my (maybe) created file. Could anyone tell me how to link them together?

I know there may be some minor bugs in this program. I will fix that later.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't instantiate the class here, are you doing that somewhere else?

Comment: When and how you are calling `Fileverifynanoha()` method? Also, please close `filewriter`.

Comment: I am not sure if it is a typo or what .. is filetxt and fileext suppose to be the same thing? if they are not, both are not being initialized.

Comment: No, all what I post is here. If possible, I want to create an object here. But I don't know why I didn't create an object.

Comment: Oh, sorry. This is a typo. fileext is what I want to use and filetxt is a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issues:

- Didn't create instance of class.
- Didn't init `File file`, so it would be null always.
- Better use `utf-8` for plain text file.

Try this:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Fileverifynanoha {
    private File file;
    private Path path;

    public Fileverifynanoha(String fp) {
        this.path = Paths.get(fp);
        this.file = path.toFile();
    }

    public void createFile()// this class wants to create a file, write something, and close it.
    {
        Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
        String s = "Takamachi Nanoha. Shirasaki Tsugumi.!";
        BufferedWriter filewriter = null;
        try {
            filewriter = Files.newBufferedWriter(path, charset);
            filewriter.write(s, 0, s.length() - 1);
            filewriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }

    }// end of this class

    /**
     * @param args
     *            the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)// the main method will check if this file contains(created), if so, return exist. if not, return doesnt exist.
    {
        Fileverifynanoha f = new Fileverifynanoha("./txttest.txt");
        f.createFile();

        if (f.file.exists() && !f.file.isDirectory())// object does not create any real thing, therefore nothing true will return.
        {
            System.out.println("File exist.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("File does not exist.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your code! I think I may know the basic on how to use a class created to do something in another class.

Comment: There is a book called `<Thinking in Java> 4th`, it would help you with `Java` & `Object-oriented` programming. If you prefer to use `Java8` then `<Core Java> 9th - volume 1` would be more up to date. Both are great books.

Answer (score 2):

You never called your constructor.

```
public static void main(String[] args)//the main method will check if this file contains(created), if so, return exist. if not, return doesnt exist.
{
    Fileverifynanoha fvn = new Fileverifynanoha();
    if (fvn.filetxt.exists()&&!fvn.filetxt.isDirectory())
    {
        System.out.println("File exist.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("File does not exist.");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: He needs to fix more than just that. the filetxt are not initialized in the class either.

Comment: Sorry. filetxt is a typo. fileext is the real thing I want to use.